# В настройках профиля нет перевода для пункта про горячие вопросы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- [Sidebar](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11546)
- [Hide Hot Network Questions](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11552)
- [When you check this box...](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11548)